# Convert the negative elements in a list to positive except the first one

Tags: python, list

How to make every element as positive in the list

```
 l =[[u'Contribution', -2.6, -2.6, -2.6, -1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.100000000000001], [u'Tax ', 
     -569.72, -569.72, -569.72, -284.86, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1994.02], [u'CityTax', -387.32, 
     -387.32, -387.32, -193.66, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
      0.0,-1355.6200000000001]]
```

the output should be like

```
  [[u'Contribution', 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.100000000000001], [u'Tax ', 
     569.72, 569.72, 569.72, 284.86, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1994.02], [u'CityTax', 387.32, 
     387.32, 387.32, 193.66, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
      0.0,1355.6200000000001]]
```

-ve values should be converted into positive and the list should be as it is

I've tried this

```
 p=[]
 k=[]   
 for i in l:
    p.append([abs(x) for x in i[1:]])
    k.append(i[0])
 for j in p:
    j.append(k[j])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comprehension will work:

```
[[x[0]] + [abs(y) for y in x[1:]] for x in l]
```

An alternative to the inner comprehension, you can use `map`:

```
[[x[0]] + list(map(abs, x[1:])) for x in l]
```

Or, most generically:

```
[[abs(y) if hasattr(y, '__abs__') else y for y in x] for x in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if non-number elements are spread across the sublists (also avoids slicing):

```
[[abs(x) if isinstance(x,(int,float)) else x for x in sublist] for sublist in l]
```

Your method is also close to correct, we just would need to join `p` and `k`:

```
[[k_sub]+p_sub for k_sub,p_sub in zip(k,p)]
```